# asynchronously XMLHttpRequest reponsse append to parent element

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml, createelement

I have created a small script to display ads on my site using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest, here is an example how it is added on html page.

```
<div>
    <script src="ad.js"></script>
    <script src="ad.js"></script>
</div>
<div>Content</div>
```

So I have a problem to display the content because it is async loaded and the response is not displayed inside the `<div>` element.

How I try to display reponse from ad.js:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "<?php echo $_GET['tag'] ?>";
div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

I know the problem is because I `appendChild` in body. Content from ad.js should be loaded where `<script src="ad.js"></script>` is placed and I have no idea how to do it, or if that is really possible without `document.write()`.

Comment: ad.js is broken, PHP doesn't run in js files. Also, loading the same js file twice won't usually work. Use a function or loop to execute the same task multiple times.

Comment: It's not broken it's served as javascript file